# Casting: why does sub-classes properties becomes inaccessible when assigned to super class variables?

Tags: java, casting

In the example below I have two classes `Super` and `Sub`. `Sub` is extending `Sup`:

```
class Super{
 int a;
 int b;
 public void superMethod(){
     System.out.println("i am SubClass");
  }
}

class Sub extends Super{
  int d;
  public void subMethod(){
     System.out.println("i am SubClass");
  }
}
```

when I try to execute this code:

```
    Super obj=new Sub();
    obj.subMethod();
```

I faced a compile time error. Where are the sub classe fields and properties being stored? Why i couldn't access them?

But when I type-cast the object by this code:

```
Sub subObj=(Sub)obj
subObj.subMethod();
```

again the fields and properties becomes accessible. How is java handling these fields and properties. How can i access the fields and properties which were not accessible from the super classes object?  I am having difficulties to understand these concept behind the scene. Please help me!!!!

Comment: You need to understand the difference between compile-time type and runtime type. (And the difference between a dynamically and a statically typed language, perhaps). The moment that you say `Super obj = sub;`, the compiler forgets that `obj` is actually a sub (compile-time type), even though at runtime it may very well be a sub.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say Super obj = new Sub() you're basically telling the compiler that the only thing that can be guaranteed is that obj is pointing to an object of the class Super. Indeed, it is actually pointing to a Sub, but if I were to tell you to take an "animal" and milk it, wouldn't you be a bit suspicious? Just me telling you that it's an animal doesn't mean that it's say a cow,or something else that can be milked. It could be a bee for all you've told it! The compiler only knows what you tell it.

However, there is of course a way to get around this when you can guarantee that the animal is indeed something that can be milked (or likewise the Super is a masked Sub). This, as you've seen, is called casting. It's basically you telling the compiler to trust you and that you know what you're doing. Of course, if you're wrong, you'll get an exception, so you need to be careful when casting.

Comment: what about when casting back, how is the process handled, specially when the object get casted is all its properties and fields return back to the way it was before assigned to the super classes object?

Comment: The object's properties and fields are never changed; they're only hidden. So yes, all the properties will stay the same. Additionally, if you have a class that overrides its superclass' method, cast it up, and call the method, the overridden version will still be called.

Answer (score 0):

Child class inherits parents attributes and methods and not the vice versa

```
Super obj=new Sub();
obj.subMethod();
```

`obj` is `Super` class reference and `Super` has no method called `subMethod`, hence the compilation error.

Comment: when the subclass variable stored in super classes object, how is java hidding the variables????

Answer (score 0):

When you write Super obj; 
It tells the compiler the type is Super, so it will only find methods that are defined in Super.

The method you call should belong to that type.

Comment: when we cast back the sub class object stored in the superclasses object, how is java making them variales and methods accesible again?